# Illegal anotation exception in jaxb using substitution in two different file

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

When I am using substution in two different xsd file then JAXB throws error:

First xsd RegTypy.xsd contains:

```
<xs:element name="AisSeznamUdajuAbstract" abstract="true"/>
<xs:element name="AisSeznamUdaju" type="AisSeznamUdajuType" substitutionGroup="AisSeznamUdajuAbstract"/>
```

Second xsd AiseoTypy.xsd contains:

```
<xs:element name="AiseoSeznamUdaju" type="AiseoSeznamUdajuEOType" substitutionGroup="reg:AisSeznamUdajuAbstract"/>
```

as you can see I am referencing AisSeznamUdajuAbstract from the first xsd

In ObjectFactory there is generated method:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:cz:isvs:aiseo:schemas:AiseoTypy:v1", name = "AiseoSeznamUdaju", substitutionHeadNamespace = "urn:cz:isvs:reg:schemas:RegTypy:v1", substitutionHeadName = "AisSeznamUdajuAbstract")
public JAXBElement<List<String>> createAiseoSeznamUdaju(List<String> value) {
    return new JAXBElement<List<String>>(_AiseoSeznamUdaju_QNAME, ((Class) List.class), null, ((List<String> ) value));
}
```

which cause illegal argument exception:

```
[com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions|No element mapping exists for "urn:cz:isvs:reg:schemas:RegTypy:v1":"AisSeznamUdajuAbstract"|?this problem is related to the following location:|??at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl(scope=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl$GLOBAL, substitutionHeadName=AisSeznamUdajuAbstract, defaultValue=?, substitutionHeadNamespace=urn:cz:isvs:reg:schemas:RegTypy:v1, namespace=urn:cz:isvs:aiseo:schemas:AiseoTypy:v1, name=AiseoSeznamUdaju)|??at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cz.isvs.aiseo.schemas.aiseotypy.v1.ObjectFactory.createAiseoSeznamUdaju(java.util.List)
```

How to resolve this exception using JAXB customization with bindings ? I cant change XSD

**UPDATE:**

in spring context I have:

```
<sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller" />

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPaths">
        <array>
            <value>...</value>
            <value>...</value>
            ...
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but when I send message to this endpoint it look like spring is creating another marshaller:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:451) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:283) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1148) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:130) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.getJaxbContext(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:216) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.createMarshaller(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:191) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.access$500(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:70) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor$Jaxb2ResultCallback.<init>(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:312) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor$Jaxb2ResultCallback.<init>(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.marshalToResponsePayload(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:100) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java:60) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.handleMethodReturnValue(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:295) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:248) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233) [spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173) [spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** The following requires that the two XML schemas have different namespaces:

When you create a `JAXBContext` on a model that was generated from multiple XML Schemas you need to do either of the following to pull in all the metadata.

1. Include the `ObjectFactory` class from each package.

   ```
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(example.foo.ObjectFactory.class, example.bar.ObjectFactory.class);
   ```
2. Include both pacakage names delimited by a colon:

   ```
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.foo:example.bar");
   ```

Comment: @hudi - Are the namespaces in the XML Schemas the same or different?  Are all the element declarations in your question top level?

Comment: namespaces are different, and yes

Comment: @hudi - Could you create a standalone JAXB example (eliminate Spring for the moment) to track down the issue.  Creating the JAXBContext on the ObjectFactory classes would be best.

Comment: I tried something else. I generated xsd RegTypy.xsd and AiseoTypy.xsd to same package and then it start working